# Inserting 1 value of a column from a list of lists into a table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list of lists 

`log = [["MD103", None, None, None, None, None], 
       ["MD102", None, None, None, None, None]]`

And i want to insert the first value of each list on a

`cur.executemany("INSERT INTO devices VALUES(?)", logValues[1],)`

I know that its wrong but i'm unable to figure how to do this. Sometimes when it works it inserts every single character to the table by separate.

Here the whole code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys


con = None
log = [["MD103", None, None, None, None, None], ["MD102", None, None, None, None, None]]

def logMovements(logValues):
try:
    con = lite.connect('netgate.db')    
    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO devices VALUES(?)", logValues[1],)
    except lite.IntegrityError:
        print "Device already on database"
    cur.commit()
    con.executemany("INSERT INTO firmwares VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,'False','None')", (logValues))
    con.commit()                   
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM devices")
    print cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM firmwares")
    print cur.fetchall()

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()

logMovements(log)
```

EDIT: This code throws this error.
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied

EDIT 2: The problem is in the first insert because second just works fine :P

Comment: `logValues[1],`: the trailing comma is probably not right.

Comment: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied` means that `logValues` does not have the correct number of arguments to replace the `?`s in the query.

Comment: `logValuel[1]` is the second list in the log, not the first item in each log sub-list. Read up on list comprehension.

Comment: Sometimes it works maybe when you use six character device name strings, and the statement takes that as a sequence matching six parameters.

Comment: @BaselShishani Yup When i put `logValue[0][0]` or a variable in the columns side, its when it starts trying to insert each caracter of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the first value from all entries:

```
devices = [entry[0] for entry in log]
cur.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO devices VALUES(?)", devices)
```

Comment: Actually, insert still  tries to insert one caracter of the string. ill post a screen:http://imgur.com/cCjdlWu